# Puppet apply:Could not find node statement with name 'default' or 'puppetserver.example.com

Tags: puppet

/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf:

```
[master]
vardir = /opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver
logdir = /var/log/puppetlabs/puppetserver
rundir = /var/run/puppetlabs/puppetserver
pidfile = /var/run/puppetlabs/puppetserver/puppetserver.pid
icodedir = /etc/puppetlabs/code
dns_alt_names=puppetserver.example.com,puppetmaster,puppet
#environmenpath = /etc/puppet/environments
#basemodulepath = /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules:/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/modules


[main]
certname = puppetserver.example.com
server = puppetserver.example.com
environment = production
runinterval = 5s
```

/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp:

```
node 'windows.example.com' {


$iis_features = ['Web-WebServer','Web-Scripting-Tools']

iis_feature { $iis_features:

   ensure => 'present',

}

}
```

I'm very new to Puppet, followed this guide:https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/centos-puppet-master-and-agent/

puppet agent --test works fine (IIS is installed)

but when trying to apply site.pp (on Puppet Server) i'm getting

```
Error: Could not find node statement with name 'default' or 'puppetserver.example.com, puppetserver.example, puppetserver, localhost' on node puppetserver.example.com
```

Can someone explain what's the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you apply a catalog or a main manifest, a node definition that matches the client certificate is required. In this case, matching node definitions for your Puppet Master would be:

> puppetserver.example.com, puppetserver.example, puppetserver, localhost

and none of those are listed in your node definitions. Note that you can also place a node definition of `default` at the end of node definitions to "catch" any nodes that are not defined previously. Documentation for node definitions in the main manifest can be found [here](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/lang_node_definitions.html).

To resolve this, you can simply add a node definition for your Puppet Server. Since you are executing `puppet apply` on the server, the manifest is being applied locally.

```
node 'windows.example.com' {
  $iis_features = ['Web-WebServer','Web-Scripting-Tools']

  iis_feature { $iis_features:
    ensure => 'present',
  }
}

node 'puppetserver.example.com' {
  notify { 'this is the puppet master': }
}

node default {
  notify { 'this node did not match any of the listed definitions': }
}
```

Note you would also be observing the error you encountered if you execute `puppet agent -t` on the Puppet Master. This behavior is not exclusive to `puppet apply`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `puppet config print manifest` in order to find out which files are loaded on puppetserver. If `manifest` [points to directory](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/dirs_manifest.html#dirs_manifest-manifest-directory-behavior) all files in the directory are parsed in alphabetical order.

```
$ puppet config print manifest --section server --environment production
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests
```

In your case puppetserver probably looks for the definition just in `site.pp`

```
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp
```

If you don't override hostname in `puppet.conf` it should be set to

```
puppet config print --section agent certname
```

then the `certname` should match just one node definition:

```
node /^www\d+$/ {
      include common
}

node 'example.com', 'example.com', 'example.com' {

}
```